# Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0 but 4.1.2 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

While migrating and existing app to Angular 11, I'm facing the following error:

```
Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0 but 4.1.2 was found instead.
```

I'm not sure from where the 4.1.2 dependency is coming. Running the tsc from the global installation returns 4.0.5:

```
tsc --version
Version 4.0.5
```

Running the local version returns the same value:

npx tsc --version
Version 4.0.5

I know that I can disable the TS version checking, but I'd really love to know from where that 4.1.2 version is coming from.

Ideas?

Comment: What does `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --version` say? Which version is specified in your package file, and is it pinned to what Angular needs (e.g. `~4.0.5`)?

Comment: It's referencing 4.1.2, but from where it's comong frpm? devDependencies references version 4.0.5...

Comment: Does it have `"4.0.5"` exactly, or `"^4.0.5"`? Do you have `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, and what does that say got resolved?

Comment: duh...it had ^...stupid mistake. thanks.